# how to add blank space at the end of each line in HTML?

Tags: html, vb.net

I am using VB.Net for my project developing. Now I want to add blank space at the end of each line using HTML code.

So can any one help me out to do this?

Comment: You need to be more precise on the question. As the blank space can be interpreted in many ways, a visually blank space, or actual white space in DOM, etc. So what you want to do?

Comment: @xiaoyi i want actual visually blank space in each line at the end.

Comment: you'd better give an example, some of your code.

Comment: What do you expect a space to do there? By HTML rules, it will be ignored, except in `pre` or `textarea` content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is special symbol for that

```
 <P>
   my line of text &nbsp; 
 </P>
```

use as many of those as needed, though is always better to simulate the spaces with CSS
like

```
 padding-right:5px;
```

Comment: good call, but the padding solution may not satisfy his *each line* requirement.

Comment: ya thats true. but i am creating string dynamically. thats why i am confused. how to do that?

Comment: @xiaoyi, yeah you're right, though it depends on what he also means by "each line", you could have paragraphs, list items, etc, if you can differentiate the elements, you can easily use the padding properly.

Comment: @BrijeshPatel yeah in that case just use the symbol whenver you need it, it will be encoded as a blank space